# SUBSTR returns no record (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, substr

```
SELECT jour 
FROM reservations 
WHERE id_user = 57 AND SUBSTR(jour,10) = '2014_08_14' ORDER BY jour
```

returns nothing...

I have a record in the database that matches the codition:

[image]

Comment: What type is the `jour` col of? Is it definitly a string coloum or a date, datetime, timestamp col?

Comment: is `jour` of type string or something else ?

Comment: If you have Problems like this just put your called function (i.e. `substr`) in your select to verify if you do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `SUBSTR(jour,10)` with `SUBSTR(jour,1,10)`.

Assumption: `jour` is a `varchar` type column. If you are storing dates as `varchar`, **do not do that!**

Explanation: My solution uses the `(str,pos,len)` overload of the `SUBSTR` function. Arguments 2 and 3 are respectively, the position to start from and the length of the substring.

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

Answer (score 2):

[`substr`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)'s first argument is the **position to start from**. Hence, `SUBSTR(jour,10)` returns `_AM`, and you get an empty result set. Instead, you should use the tree argument variant:

```
SELECT   jour
FROM     reservations 
WHERE    id_user = 57 AND 
         SUBSTR(jour, 1, 10) = '2014_08_14' -- Here
ORDER BY jour
```

To make your query more readable and ensure such mistakes aren't repeated, you could use the following variant:

```
SELECT   jour
FROM     reservations 
WHERE    id_user = 57 AND 
         SUBSTR(jour FROM 1 FOR 10) = '2014_08_14' -- Here
ORDER BY jour
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [**LEFT(str,len)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function or [**SUBSTR(str,pos,len)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

Try this:

```
SELECT jour 
FROM reservations 
WHERE id_user = 57 AND LEFT(jour, 10) = '2014_08_14' 
ORDER BY jour
```

**OR**

```
SELECT jour 
FROM reservations 
WHERE id_user = 57 AND SUBSTR(jour, 1, 10) = '2014_08_14' 
ORDER BY jour
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do Select SUBSTR(jour,10) from reservations do you get exactly: '2014_08_14'? I believe  you need to do  SUBSTR(jour,1,10).